# Comparar un elemento de una matriz con el siguiente y si es igual eliminar la fila completa en python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

Tengo esta matriz

> [image: Matriz]

y requiero eliminar la filas que tengan repetido los elementos de la segunda columna

Necesito que quede algo así:

> [image: Matriz requerida]

Tengo este código:

```
for i in range(a,b):
    if lines3[i-1,1] == lines3[i,1]:
        lines4 = np.delete(lines3,i,0)

print(lines4)
```

y me queda así

> ```
> [[1581 1243 2459 1260]
>  [1581 1243 2459 1257]
>  [1581 1244 2459 1260]
>  [1581 2018 2459 2032]]
> ```

Comment: Fatima no me queda clara una cosa, ¿es comparar una fila con la siguiente  o ver si esa fila tiene el elmento de la segunda columna repetido en cualquier otra fila de la matriz(no tiene por que ser la siguiente, cualquiera)? Si es una fila con la siguiente, ¿la última fila no la comparas con ninguna?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, por ejemplo en la fila 1, 2 y 3 en la columna 2 tengo  el valor de 1243 de esas tres filas requiero que solo quede una

Comment: Ya edite un poco la publicación creo se entiende mejor

Comment: A ver si consigo hacerme entender, ¿Que pasaria si la segunda fila estubiera al final? ¿Quedarian dos filas con el mismo valor en la segunda columna al estar separadas o el resultado sería el mismo?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la segunda columna de la matriz previamente ya la tengo ordenada de menor a mayor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas reinventar la rueda en principio, ya hay algo en Numpy que hace eso por ti, [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). Retorna los elementos únicos de un array, pero si le pasamos el parametro `index` como `True` entonces  retorna un segundo array que contiene los índices de esos elementos, y si hay más de uno retorna el indice del primero encontrado.

Aplicandolo sobre la columna en cuestión (la segunda columna de tu matriz) solo hace falta hacer slicing posteriormente sobre tu matriz usando ese array.

En tu caso hay un problema, quieres que en la matriz final quede la última fila que tiene la columna repetida y no la primera. Podrias hacer que la matriz quede ordenada de la forma apropiada, algo así:

> ```
> [[1581  1243  2459  1257]
>  [1581  1243  2459  1259]
>  [1581  1243  2459  1260] 
>  [1581  1244  2459  1260] 
>  [1581  2018  2459  2032]]
> ```

No obstante tal y como la tienes podemos usar otro parámetro de [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), `return_counts` que nos da las veces que aparece repetidos esos elementos y recalcular los índices:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array([[1581,  1243,  2459,  1260], 
                   [1581,  1243,  2459,  1259], 
                   [1581,  1243,  2459,  1257], 
                   [1581,  1244,  2459,  1260], 
                   [1581,  2018,  2459,  2032]])

_, indices, counts = np.unique(matriz[:,1], return_index=True,  return_counts = True)
filtro = counts + indices - 1
matriz = matriz[filtro, :]

print(matriz)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> [[1581 1243 2459 1257]
>  [1581 1244 2459 1260]
>  [1581 2018 2459 2032]]
> ```

**Advertencia:** para que funcione de forma apropiada este código tu matriz debe estar ordenada previamente de la forma que lo está la tuya. Es decir, la matriz tiene que estar previamente ordenada de forma que las filas con el mismo elemento en la segunda columna están juntas y el último de cada grupo es el que quieres en tu matriz final.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ha sido de gran utilidad!

Comment: @Fatima, me alegro de que te fuera útil, si tienes cualquier duda solo comentalo. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y de hecho si tengo otra duda, ahora tengo una matriz en la que deseo eliminar la filas según el valor de la columna 2. Por ejemplo si la fila 1, 2, 3, 4 de la columna 2  tiene un valor muy cercano o dentro de un rango que yo determine, se eliminen las filas de valores parecidos y solo conservar 1 de ellas.                                 `[1586   **86** 2070   72]
[1586   **88** 2070   73]
[1586   **89** 2070   74]
[1586  165 2070  149]
[1586  166 2070  150]
[1586  243 2070  228]
[1586  245 2070  229]
[1586  307 2070  307]
[1586  308 2070  308]
[1586  309 2070  309]]`

Comment: @Fatima creo que seria bueno que crearas otra pregunta aclarandolo todo bién, con una salida esperada y algún código que estes intentando para que no te la cierren. Aunque similar a la pregunta actual creo que tiene las suficientes diferencias para plantearlo en otra. Una aclaración que debes hacer es si quieres eliminar las filas que tengan su columna 2 separadas por un rango (por ejemplo, dejar una de todas las que esten separadas por menos de 10 unidades, o hacer esto pero dando un rango, las que esten entre 80 y 90 por ejemplo.  Saludos.